# Effective way to search ZIP for an XML file with hashed name

Tags: java, xml, hash, zip

I have a zip file, which contains lots of folders and XML files and I want to select a specific file. But the file's name is hashed so I can't really tell what it might be, because it's generated by other application.

[image: ZIP files]
Is there some effective way to select this XML file? I have this information:

- The file name is unique for every zip file.
- It is located directly in the zip, not in any sub-folder.
- It is the only XML file with hashed name, other file names are know, but their count might vary.

I'm trying to avoid comparing every file name with some predefined list of names, but so far I couldn't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filename has a pattern, you can try parsing it and see if it matches the pattern.

- Unzip the content
- place yourself in the unzip directory
- create a method that parse the directory

  - if the current object parsed is a directory, call recursively that method
  - if the current object parsed is a file with .xml extension, check if it matches the pattern like this (it will return true if it matches):

  `filename.matches('.+\\-.+\\-.+\\-.+\\-.+);`

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. Luckily I don't need to check sub-folder, so it might be quick. I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: Thanks again, it works like a charm. Just a small mistake in your regex, it should be this: `.matches(".+\\-.+\\-.+\\-.+\\-.+")`